# Ruby method return more than one variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to return to my Rails view more than one variable from method... But how could i do this?

For example now i have

```
def my1
 @price = 1
 @price
end
```

but how could i also return other valuem somethin like:

```
def my1
 @qnt = 2
 @price = 1
 @price, @qnt
end
```

?

Also my idea is to split them to string like

```
@price + "/-/" + @qnt
```

and then just split them via /-/ in view.... But this is a bad practice...
So how could i get from one method two or more variables?

Answer (score 2):

Return an array:

```
def my1
 qnt = 2
 price = 1
 [price, qnt]
end
```

then you can do this:

```
p, q = my1() # parentheses to emphasize a method call
# do something with p and q
```

### Option 2

Or you can return a custom object, like this:

```
require 'ostruct'

def my1
 qnt = 2
 price = 1

 OpenStruct.new(price: price, quantity: qnt)
end


res = my1() # parentheses to emphasize a method call

res.quantity # => 2
res.price # => 1
```

Comment: hm, how to get? didn't understand... in view something like = my1.p ? or what?

Comment: There's usage scenario in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use another object that will hold the variables and return it. You can then access the variables from that object;

Answer (score 0):

### Array

The easiest way is to return an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html):

```
def my1
  @qnt = 2
  @price = 1
  [ @price, @qnt ]
end

price, quantity = my1
```

### Hash

But you could also return a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html):

```
def my1
  @qnt = 2
  @price = 1
  { :quantity => @qnt, :price = @price
end

return_value = my1

price = return_value[:price]
quantity = return_value[:quantity]
# or
price, quantity = [ return_value[:price], return_value[:quantity] ]
```

### Custom Class

Or a custom Class:

```
class ValueHolder
  attr_reader :quantity, :price

  def initialize(quantity, price)
    @quantity = quantity
    @price = price
  end
end

def my1
  @qnt = 2
  @price = 1
  ValueHolder.new(@qnt, @price)
end

value_holder = my1

price = value_holder.price
quantity = value_holder.quantity
# or
price, quantity = [ value_holder.price, value_holder.quantity ]
```

### OpenStruct

You could use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) as [Sergio mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624936/221213).

Comment: You could use open struct instead of custom object. See my answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you, I was not aware of this class.

Comment: Hey, you copied my answer! :)

Comment: I did not copy that, but I changed it.